# SQL Server dbname from table syslogins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a software that uses the field dbname from table **'dbo.syslogins'**. Thanks to this I'm able to know which database belongs to a user (which is the input parameter).

A few weeks ago we had a problem with the SQL Server that forced us to restore the entire server. We don't know in which step of the process happens that if I make:

```sql
SELECT loginname, dbname
FROM master.dbo.syslogins
where dbname = 'master'
order by dbname
```

The major part of the users **are linked with 'master' instead of his database**. This still occurs If I link the login again to the database.

How can I make appear in the dbname field the correct database again?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change default database for login.